# Merging Arrays of Shift Objects to Create a Final Shift Schedule

Tags: node.js, typescript, algorithm, data-structures

I am working on a shift scheduling system and need assistance with merging two arrays of shift objects. Each shift object is defined as follows:

`type Shift = { start: Date, end: Date, users: string[] }`

The first array represents upcoming shifts, where consecutive elements have no spacing between their end and start times. The second array contains "overrides," which are scattered shifts that can be set to any time without overlapping.

My goal is to merge these two arrays into a single array that represents the final shift schedule. However, I'm struggling to handle all the variations, such as overrides engulfing an entire shift or overrides occurring in the middle of a shift.

Is there a suitable data structure for this scenario and any algorithmic approaches that can help me achieve this calculation efficiently?

-- EDIT --

shifts array -

```
[
{start: "01-07-2023 00:00", end: "02-07-2023 00:00", users: ['a']},
{start: "02-07-2023 00:00", end: "03-07-2023 00:00", users: ['b']},
{start: "03-07-2023 00:00", end: "04-07-2023 00:00", users: ['c']},
{start: "04-07-2023 00:00", end: "05-07-2023 00:00", users: ['a']},
{start: "05-07-2023 00:00", end: "06-07-2023 00:00", users: ['b']}
]
```

overrides:

```
[
{start: "01-07-2023 10:00", end: "01-07-2023 15:00", users: ['d']},
{start: "04-07-2023 01:00", end: "05-07-2023 12:00", users: ['e']},
{start: "02-07-2023 00:00", end: "03-07-2023 00:00", users: ['f']}
]
```

final result -

```
[
{start: "01-07-2023 00:00", end: "01-07-2023 10:00", users: ['a']},
{start: "01-07-2023 10:00", end: "01-07-2023 15:00", users: ['d']},
{start: "01-07-2023 15:00", end: "02-07-2023 00:00", users: ['a']},
{start: "02-07-2023 00:00", end: "03-07-2023 00:00", users: ['f']},
{start: "03-07-2023 00:00", end: "04-07-2023 00:00", users: ['c']},
{start: "04-07-2023 00:00", end: "04-07-2023 01:00", users: ['a']},
{start: "04-07-2023 01:00", end: "05-07-2023 12:00", users: ['e']},
{start: "05-07-2023 12:00", end: "06-07-2023 00:00", users: ['b']}
]
```

Comment: Please provide examples of all scenarios of overlapping and the corresponding expected results. Currently it is not clear how you want to determine a final schedule.

Comment: @trincot added an example

Comment: Could you modify your dates so they are in some standard ISO format (and thus orderable lexicographically) or actual `Date`s (and thus orderable normally)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort both arrays by start date (convert to ISO format for lexical ordering), and then perform a merge by clipping the shifts that cross either side of the override and skipping those that are completely overlapped.

```js
// Helper functions to toggle between DMY and YMD formats, to make dates lexically ordered:
const toggleIso = (s) => s?.replace(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+) (.*)$/, "$3-$2-$1 $4");
const toggleIsoMap = arr =>
    arr.map(o => ({ ...o, start: toggleIso(o.start), end: toggleIso(o.end) }))
       .sort((a, b) => a.start.localeCompare(b.start));

function mergeShifts(shifts, overrides) {
    overrides = toggleIsoMap(overrides);
    const shiftIter = toggleIsoMap(shifts).values();
    const nextShift = () => shiftIter.next().value;

    const result = [];

    let shift = nextShift();    
    for (const override of overrides) {
        // Flush all shifts that come before this override
        while (shift?.end < override.start) { 
            result.push(shift);
            shift = nextShift();
        }
        // The override may make a shift end sooner
        if (shift?.start < override.start) result.push({...shift, end: override.start });
        result.push(override);
        // Skip shifts that are entirely within the override
        while (shift?.end <= override.end) shift = nextShift();
        // The override may make a shift start later
        if (shift?.start < override.end) shift = {...shift, start: override.end };
    }
    if (shift) result.push(shift);
    return toggleIsoMap(result.concat(...shiftIter));
}

// Run with your example input 
const shifts = [
    {start: "01-07-2023 00:00", end: "02-07-2023 00:00", users: ['a']},
    {start: "02-07-2023 00:00", end: "03-07-2023 00:00", users: ['b']},
    {start: "03-07-2023 00:00", end: "04-07-2023 00:00", users: ['c']},
    {start: "04-07-2023 00:00", end: "05-07-2023 00:00", users: ['a']},
    {start: "05-07-2023 00:00", end: "06-07-2023 00:00", users: ['b']}
];
const overrides = [
    {start: "01-07-2023 10:00", end: "01-07-2023 15:00", users: ['d']},
    {start: "04-07-2023 01:00", end: "05-07-2023 12:00", users: ['e']},
    {start: "02-07-2023 00:00", end: "03-07-2023 00:00", users: ['f']}
];

const result = mergeShifts(shifts, overrides);
for (const entry of result) console.log(JSON.stringify(entry));
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Make a list `points: Date[]` of all start and end date points, including overrides ones together. Sort them and filted to be unique.
2. Split shifts/overrides array items on that points into smaller items using `[].flatMap(item => [piece1, piece2, piece3])` on the points from `points` list. Now if some of them overlap, it will be a complete overlap. You may use binary search on the sorted `points` if you really want to be efficient.
3. Now when all the items have the start/end of the same set, replace the matching ones from `shifts` with `overrides`, 1-to-1 (they are splitted in smallest intervals of `points` start/ends, so they can't overlap)
4. Generally ChatGPT probably would answer this question, try it next time. It's fine for straigntforward things like this afaik